# Parse_url equivalent in grails / groovy?

Tags: parsing, url, grails, groovy, url-mapping

Is there a groovy/grails equivalent to PHP's parse_url ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php ) or python's urlparse ( http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html )  that turns a URL string into a struct containing host,protocol, querystring, fragment, URI, etc?

I thought it might be in the grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/util/WebUtils.html , but didnt see anything. I dont think HTTPBuilder or assorted URLMapping utilities are what I need.

I really just want to pull a map out of the path and queryString and handle the edge cases (array of params  `/blah/fuzz?foo=bar&foo=baz`, fragments `/blah/fuzz?foo=bar#baz`, encoded URLs for redirects) correctly.

I know I can handle the PATH component via clever use of URLMapping  eg: `/blah/$code`, but im left with decoding the param block...

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly, what you really need is plain old [URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class:

```
new URI('http://google.com/?q=URL').query
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending @Artur Nowak answer, maybe you will need some more effort to get what you want. Here is an example:

```
URI dbUri = new URI('http://google.com/?q=URL')
def username = dbUri?.getUserInfo()?.split(":")?.getAt(0)
def password = dbUri?.getUserInfo()?.split(":")?.getAt(1)
def host = dbUri?.getHost()
def databaseInstance = dbUri?.getPath()
def url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + databaseInstance
```